# N-ary Tree implementation: cannot convert 'Tree::node*' to 'node*' in assignment

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, tree, mingw

I am trying to make a n-ary tree with a List of Lists implemented with pointers, this is my implementation of my `Tree`:

```
class Tree{
public:

struct nodeSon{
    struct node* node_ptr;
    nodeSon* nextNodeSon_ptr;
};

struct node{
    char label;
    node* nextNode_ptr;
    struct nodeSon* nSon;
};

node* root;

void AddSon(int i, node n, char l); //Adds a son with label l to n at i position
};
```

The problem happens when I try to implement `Tree::AddSon()`:

```
void Tree::AddSon(int i, nodo n, char l){

node* nextPtr = root->nextNode_ptr;
node* newNode = new node();
newNode->label= l;
root->nextNode_ptr = newNode;
newNode->nextNode_ptr = nextPtr;

node* it = root;
while (it != &n) {
    it = it->nextNode_ptr;
}

nodeSon* it2 = it->nSon;
int counter = 1;
while (contador != i) {
    it2 = it2->sigNodoHijo_ptr;
}
nodeSon* nextPtrNH = it2->nextNodeSon_ptr;
nodeSon* newNodeNH = new nodeSon();
newNodeNH->node_ptr = newNodo; //error indication at this line
it2 = newNodeNH;
newNodoNH->nextNodeSon_ptr = nextPtrNH;
.
.
.
}
```

I receive this error when I try to build it:

```
Tree.cpp:110:27: error: cannot convert 'Tree::node*' to 'node*' in assignment
```

---

- Why does this happen?
- How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The Problem

```
class Tree{
  public:

    struct nodeSon{
      struct node* node_ptr;    // (1)
      nodeSon* nextNodeSon_ptr;
    };
};
```

At `(1)` you are basically telling the compiler that `node_ptr` shall point towards a type that you have not yet defined, but that the definition of this type will be available at a later time.

The problem is that the compiler cannot assume that this type resides within `class Tree`—since you have not said that this is the case—instead it will assume that `struct node` refers to a type in the *global* namespace.

When you later declare a type named `node` inside `class Tree` it is already too late; the type of `Tree::nodeSon::node_ptr` will not change just because a more (from our perspective) suitable type has become available.

---

#### Example

We can reproduce your error with the following, much reduced, testcase.

```
struct A {
  struct B {
    struct C * ptr;
  };

  struct C { };
};
```

```
struct C { };
```

```
int main () {
  A::B x;
  A::C y;
  C    z;

  x.ptr = &y; // error,  `y` is of type `A::c`
  x.ptr = &z; // ok,     `z` is of type `::C`
}
```

---

#### The Solution

You will need to tell the compiler that there will exist a type named `node` in `Tree` by forward-declaring it, prior to writing the definition of `Tree::nodeSon`.

```
class Tree{
  public:
    struct node; // forward-declare Tree::node

    struct nodeSon{
      struct node* node_ptr;
      nodeSon* nextNodeSon_ptr;
    };

    struct node{
      char label;
      node* nextNode_ptr;
      struct nodeSon* nSon;
    };

    node* root;

    void AddSon (int i, node n, char l); //Adds a son with label l to n at i position
};
```

Comment: You, sir, have gotten a lot better in explaining over the last year (or two?)

Comment: @sehe I started teaching about a year and a half ago, maybe that's the underlying reason! `:D`

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Amazing explanation! :D Pretty clear and punctual. Thank you so much that definitely solves my problem.